# Laravel 5.6 Unable to connect MS SQL Server 2008 R2 from PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server-2008

I am using Laravel 5.6, and trying to connect with MS SQL Server 2008 R2, all running on local machine. I have a test database named "ItemMaster", which is working fine with my C#.Net application.

When I try to connect same database from Laravel, I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (SQL: select * from ITEM_CATEGORY)
```

Can anybody suggest how to fix this.

In config/database.php, I have setup `sqlsrv` driver as follows:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'MY-PC\MYSQL2008R2'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'ITEMMASTER'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'myuser'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

Getting error on this line inside my controller:

```
$items = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('select * from ITEM_CATEGORY');
```

I installed [Microsoft Drivers 4.3 for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55642) and copied file `php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86.dll` to `php/ext` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution for this problem, sharing might help someone else making same mistake.

Actually the mistake is how I defined SQL Connection parameters in `config/database.php`

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'MY-PC\MYSQL2008R2'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'ITEMMASTER'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'myuser'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

In this code segment, I actually defined my parameters as second parameter to `env()` which (be-definition) is not the real value but will be used as default value if that specific key is not found in `.env` file.

You can read more about Environment configuration [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#environment-configuration)

So the final code segment should be like this:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => 'MY-PC\MYSQL2008R2',
            'port' => '1433',
            'database' => 'ITEMMASTER',
            'username' => 'myuser',
            'password' => 'mypassword',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

Or another alternative may be to define these parameters in `.env` file, in the root directory of your application .

Comment: It was using env file and reading from that. Actually I put my values but that should be placed directly, and should not with env function. Because env function will first look for value from env file, and if it doesn't found, then it will return the value which I placed in second argument.... Ultimately It was my typing mistake.